# Scala: where to put the @unchecked annotation in a foreach

Tags: scala, foreach, unchecked

I have the following:

```
samples.sliding(2).foreach{case List(a, b)=> printf("%x %x\n", a.value, b.value)}
```

I know that the single 'case' will match all the possible values but I get a 'match is not exhaustive' warning.  The Scala book explains where to put the @unchecked annotation on a normal fully-specified match expression, but not for the form above.  How do I annotate the above to stop the compiler from complaining?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@unchecked` is *only* defined for the selector in a match operation, not for arbitrary functions.  So you could

```
foreach{ x => (x: @unchecked) => x match { case List(a,b) => ... } }
```

but that is rather a mouthful.

Alternatively, you could create a method that unsafely converts a partial function to a complete one (which actually just casts to the function superclass of `PartialFunction`):

```
def checkless[A,B](pf: PartialFunction[A,B]): A => B = pf: A => B
```

and then you can

```
samples.sliding(2).foreach(checkless{
  case List(a,b) => printf("%x %x\n", a.value, b.value)
})
```

and you don't have any warnings because it was expecting a partial function.

Comment: I got there just after you posted, thanks anyway - although I was hoping for some rep points for answering my own question ;-)  The PF to CF conversion is tricksy because there's no explicit cast, although I see what it is up to.  Thanks, both for the answer and for the checkless method.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about `@unchecked`, but why not just call `x.head` and `x.tail.head` or `x(0)` and  `x(1)`?

Comment: Yes, that would work but I rather like Scala's match operator :-)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you add an  dummy case, if you're sure it will never happen?

```
samples.sliding (2).foreach {
  case List (a, b) => printf ("%x %x\n", a.value, b.value)
  case _           => sys.error ("impossible")
}
```

Comment: Because I know the catchall will never get taken and it's therefore unnecessary.  I could do it with a separate def and annotate that as documented on p288 of the ProgInScala book but I'm trying to figure out how to annotate a foreach, as I said in the question.